# Copy constructors with move-only, but cloneable types in member containers

Tags: c++, c++11

Assume that we have two types, `T1` and `T2`.

`T1` isn't important except the following facts:

- it isn't copy constructible
- it has a move constructor
- we have an excellent function with the signature `T1 copy(T1 const& orig)`, which creates a copy.

`T2` can be simplified to the following class:

```
// T2.h
class T2 {
public:
    T2() { /* initializes the vector with something */ }
    T2(T2 const& other);
private:
    std::vector<T1> v;
}

// T2.cpp

T2::T2(T2 const& other) : ... {}
```

How would you implement this method, if you could only write to the ellipsis part, or to the global scope?

A simple real world use case - assuming the "you can't write anything between the curly braces" part is a real world restriction:

- `T1` is `std::unique_ptr<anything>`
- `copy` is `std::make_unique`
- `anything` has a copy constructor

I also have two additional requirements for the implementation:

- performance. It shouldn't be (considerably) slower than the naive implementation with a `for` loop in the copy constructor's body.
- readability. The entire point behind the question is to do something which is more clear/clean than the trivial for loop (e.g. imagine T2 with two or more member vectors).

And optional, but nice to have features:

- something that's easily generalized to other containers
- something that works with just iterators
- something that's generic

A clarification: I know the question is trivially solvable with a `std::vector<T1> copy_vec(std::vector<T1> const& orig)` global function. Placing that function into an anonymous namespace within `T2.cpp` would also make it local, but I would argue against its readability, I think it wouldn't be better than the for loop at all. And it's clearly a bad solution if the copy constructor isn't in an implementation file but inlined in the header.

So a rephrasing of my question is:

- Is there already something similar implemented, which I can just include?
- If there is none, then why? I'm not saying I thought about every corner case, but I think this is something that possibly can be implemented in a nice generic way, and thanks to `unique_ptr`, it's a common enough case.

Comment: You do realize that you can just make a function that takes `other.v` and returns the copied `vector`, right?

Comment: Yes, I did mention that in my question. But is there really no existing functionality to copy a container containing types with no copy constructor but with some clone method, with a single statement?

Comment: That was a typo, I wrote `T2` instead of `T1`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with a naive loop:

```
v.reserve(other.v.size());
for (auto& elem : other.v) {
    v.push_back(copy(elem));
}
```

That's plenty readable and optimal.

Though I guess the modern, clever solution with be to use [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/):

```
T2(T2 const& other)
: v(other.v | view::transform(copy))
{ }
```

I'm not sure that's enough better than the loop to justify the additional complexity but YMMV.

Comment: Based on the examples, `range-v3` looks promising, yes. I would argue against the complexity, depending on the code, the intent  of the transform version could be much cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: It's significantly faster than the for loop or my version based on my first tests, which is definitely interesting, I'll try to figure out why tomorrow.

Comment: More tests: depending on the compiler, flags, and build type (single TU or normal) the difference in execution time is between -5 and +20 percent. (it's only better than the for loop when compiled with -O2 using unified build). It's probably a good trade off for the simpler source code and other possibilities with it.